# How to use the split function on every row in a dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I want to count the number of times a word is being repeated in the review string

I am reading the csv file and storing it in a python dataframe using the below line

```
reviews = pd.read_csv("amazon_baby.csv")
```

The code in the below lines work when I apply it to a single review.

```
print reviews["review"][1]
a = reviews["review"][1].split("disappointed")
print a
b = len(a)
print b
```

The output for the above lines were

```
it came early and was not disappointed. i love planet wise bags and now my wipe holder. it keps my osocozy wipes moist and does not leak. highly recommend it.
['it came early and was not ', '. i love planet wise bags and now my wipe holder. it keps my osocozy wipes moist and does not leak. highly recommend it.']
2
```

When I apply the same logic to the entire dataframe using the below line. I receive an error message

```
reviews['disappointed'] = len(reviews["review"].split("disappointed"))-1
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/gouta/PycharmProjects/MLCourse1/Classifier.py", line 12, in <module>
    reviews['disappointed'] = len(reviews["review"].split("disappointed"))-1
  File "C:\Users\gouta\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2360, in __getattr__
    (type(self).__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're trying to split the entire review column of the data frame (which is the Series mentioned in the error message). What you want to do is apply a function to each row of the data frame, which you can do by calling [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) on the data frame:

```
f = lambda x: len(x["review"].split("disappointed")) -1
reviews["disappointed"] = reviews.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Comment: Do I need to add any other lines to this code other than reading the data into the reviews variable? Because the above two lines did not work.

Comment: I think it should work as written, but I didn't test it. What went wrong?

Comment: File "Classifier.py", line 18, in <module>
    reviews["disappointed"] = reviews.apply(f, axis=1)
  File "pandas\core\frame.py", line 3972, in apply
    return self._apply_standard(f, axis, reduce=reduce)
  File "pandas\core\frame.py", line 4064, in _apply_standard
    results[i] = func(v)
  File "Classifier.py", line 17, in <lambda>
    f = lambda x: len(reviews["review"].split("disappointed")) -1
  File "pandas\core\generic.py", line 2360, in __getattr__
    (type(self).__name__, name))
AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'split'", u'occurred at index 0')

Comment: Oops. It should be `lambda x: len(x["review"].split("disappointed")) -1`. `x` is then the row being passed to the function not the whole data frame itself.

Answer (score 16):

pandas 0.20.3 has **pandas.Series.str.split()** which acts on every string of the series and does the split. So you can simply split and then count the number of splits made

```
len(reviews['review'].str.split('disappointed')) - 1
```

[pandas.Series.str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html)

Comment: I think this is the most Pandas-y solution, and probably faster. Wonder if the OP got a chance to do performance testing on it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the problem is with:

```
reviews["review"]
```

The above is a Series. In your first snippet, you are doing this:

```
reviews["review"][1].split("disappointed")
```

That is, you are putting an index for the review. You could try looping over all rows of the column and perform your desired action. For example:

```
for index, row in reviews.iterrows():
    print len(row['review'].split("disappointed"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.str` to use string methods on series of strings:

```
reviews["review"].str.split("disappointed")
```

Comment: str won't solve the problem. reviews["review"] gives a series of strings not one string.

Comment: @OzgurOzturk It does solve the problem of applying `split` to each row. Id does not solve the problem of computing the lengths because I thought that was easy enough. And I know that `reviews["review"]` is a series of strings. Why did you think I don't?

Comment: This sort of worked for my problem....how would you get only the value after the split for the series?

Comment: @santma I don't know what you mean by "the value" here. You might want to ask a new question, including a [mcve].

Comment: @StopharmingMonica When I use .split(), I get both sides of the split() returned. For example, I have a list of URLs in a dataframe that follow this format: 'https://www.domain.co/product/product-name/'. I'd like to get just "product-name". When I used .split("product/") I get ["https://www.domain.co/","product-name/"].