# Replace abbreviation or slang word in Indonesian

Tags: python, abbreviation

i have a lot of text data like this in excel files
[raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdWuH.png)

and a list of dictionary from slang or abbreviations word in Indonesia from txt files
[slang/abbreviation word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJCln.png)

How to replace the word in the text based on the dictionary that i've made before?

Comment: Please do not share picture of text. You can instead edit your question and copy paste some rows of your dataframe and some lines of you slang dictionnary. Also consider adding the `nlp` (natural language processing) tag.

Comment: Thankyou for the feedback. I cant add nlp because my repution isnt sufficient for that. You can help me by answering that asap because I need the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way (this an example for one string):

```
string = 'asd des sdss d'
replacements = {"asd": "replaced"}
new_string = " ".join(replacements.get(word, word) for word in string.split(' '))
print(new_string)

result: 'replaced des sdss d'
```

This does not take care of special characters in the text like `','` or `'.'`. Maybe you need to add logic to take care of these things.

Comment: How the code if there is lot of the data in excel ?

Comment: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split' I got this error when I try in pandas data frame. How could be the code??

Comment: I can't share a code if I don't have a minimal example of your code. But for your error, with a quick search, I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/36108422/8902782